# How to prevent mesh stretching when using Inverse kinematics body constraint?

Tags: modeling, mesh, constraints

My squid mesh's tentacles each have an Inverse Kinematics body constraint for that group of tentacle bones. The bones follow the furthest bone. I need a chain length of 6 or 7 to use all bones in that leg. When I do the mesh stretches the top of the squid's body. Is there a way of preventing this? I have already adjusted the weight paint in each bone of the armature.

Thank you for your time and help[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see if you select one of these vertices (open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights*), it is part of a lot of vertex groups. It happened for some reason but I can't tell why:

[image]

In order to remove all these vertices from all groups, select them all, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups* and click on *Remove from All Groups*:

[image]

Now select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the 2 head bones with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> and go into the header menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

Also don't you need bones for the neck?

Comment: You are a miracle worker!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was ripping my hair out trying to figure out!! Works perfectly!!!

Comment: Yes, I just added bones for the neck too :)